# Minimum integer in PHP 7

Tags: php, integer-overflow

In interactive mode on PHP 7 (64 bit Ubuntu),

```
php > echo true;
1
php > echo false; # no output for false
php > echo PHP_INT_MIN == -9223372036854775808;
1
php > echo is_int(PHP_INT_MIN);
1
php > echo is_int(-9223372036854775808);
```

Why doesn't the last line output 1?

Comment: Add some more info

Comment: Ok echo PHP_INT_MIN === -9223372036854775808; is false. Nonetheless, echo PHP_INT_MIN; displays -9223372036854775808 and echo is_int(-9223372036854775808); is false

Comment: Sorry I'm wondering why the value displayed by PHP_INT_MIN does not appear to be an integer when checking with is_int()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var_dump()` is your friend.

```
var_dump(
    PHP_INT_MIN,
    is_int(PHP_INT_MIN),
    -9223372036854775808,
    is_int(-9223372036854775808)
);

/* Output:
int(-9223372036854775808)
bool(true)
float(-9.2233720368548E+18)
bool(false)
*/
```

Answer (score 3):

Because [is_int](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) :

> perates in signed fashion, not unsigned, and is limited to the word size of the environment php is running in.

and so -9223372036854775808 it's smaller than your system word bound

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Would have accepted this as an answer had I not done so already

Comment: The comment you cite from the PHP.net comments looks invalid in PHP7 to me, as integers can be signed. (See my answer)

Answer (score 2):

First PHP parses your integer value as float, because of an integer overflow. Then it uses is_int() to determine if what PHP has parsed is an [integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php). See example #3 for 64-bit systems.

Please note that is_int() does work with unsigned integers as well.
Using 32-bit PHP 7:

```
echo PHP_INT_MIN;                    // -2147483648
echo var_dump(is_int(-2147483648));  // bool(false)
echo var_dump(is_int(-2147483647));  // bool(true)
```

To make sure PHP_INT_MIN is off by one, please try this on your 64-bit PHP 7:

```
echo var_dump(is_int(-9223372036854775807));  // bool(true)?
```

If you need more integer precision, you could use the [GMP extension](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php).